# Dynamically allocating length to an objective C static array

Tags: objective-c, ios, static, nsmutablearray, dynamic-arrays

Hi I am relatively new to programming on iOS and using objective C. Recently I have come across an issue I cannot seem to solve, I am writing a OBJ model loader to use within my iOS programming. For this I use two arrays as below:

```
static CGFloat modelVertices[360*9]={};
static CGFloat modelColours[360*12]={};
```

As can be seen the length is currently allocated with a hard coded value of 360 (the number of faces in a particular model). Is there no way this can be dynamically allocated from a value that has been calculated after reading the OBJ file as is done below?

```
int numOfVertices = //whatever this is read from file;
static CGFloat modelColours[numOfVertices*12]={};
```

I have tried using NSMutable arrays but found these difficult to use as when it comes to actually drawing the mesh gathered I need to use this code:

```
-(void)render
{
// load arrays into the engine
glVertexPointer(vertexStride, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexes);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glColorPointer(colorStride, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors);   
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

//render
glDrawArrays(renderStyle, 0, vertexCount);  
}
```

As you can see the command glVertexPointer requires the values as a CGFloat array:

```
glVertexPointer (GLint size, GLenum type, GLsizei stride, const GLvoid *pointer);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a static variable, its size and initial value must be known at compile time. What you can do is declare the variable as a pointer instead of an array, the use `malloc` or `calloc` to allocate space for the array and store the result in your variable.

```
static CGFloat *modelColours = NULL;

int numOfVertices = //whatever this is read from file;
if(modelColours == NULL) {
    modelColours = (CGFloat *)calloc(sizeof(CGFloat),numOfVertices*12);
}
```

I used `calloc` instead of `malloc` here because a static array would be filled with 0s by default, and this would ensure that the code was consistent.

Comment: Again, one should never mention malloc or calloc to a newbie without mentioning the need to do free on the other end.

Comment: Thanks, this worked using calloc, I can now finally get to sleep!

@DanielRHicks about freeing the memory, good point,  I will look into trying to do this tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a c-style malloc to dynamically allocate space for the array.

```
int numOfVertices = //whatever this is read from file;
CGFloat *modelColours = (CGFloat *) malloc(sizeof(CGFloat) * numOfVertices);
```

Comment: Of course, if one does that they need to be sure to free the array space at the appropriate time.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried this one, and this works great too. And takes up less line of text!